# MySQL tables name guide style

Tags: php, mysql, nomenclature

I would like to know which is the more correct way to name the tables and fields in a MySQL database .

And how to differentiate tables that are intermediate tables .

Examples:

**Table name:**
*users* or *user*

**foreign key columns:** 
*user_id* or *id* or *user_ID*

**Table with two words:**
*purchased_point* or *point_puchased* or *pointpuchased*

**Itermediate table (many to many)**
*users_sites* or *user_sites* or *usersites*

Is there a some "style guide" like: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html

Comment: there's no right/wrong way. there's only guides, which ultimately are purely opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All caps. Different words separator is _ underscore.

Master or parent tables prefix MSTR
Child tables prefix MPNG
Transaction tables where multiple parents are referred as TRXN

Post fix all tables as _TBL

Use singular names for tables as user and not users

E.g. MSTR_USER_TBL, MPNG_ACCOUNT_TBL, TRXN_CART_ITEM_TBL

These conventions i follow. Makes simpler to read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what we do is standard but here is what we do :

- We use singular name. Plural is unnecessary : we already know there can be more than one user in the table `User`.
- Our database is used with a Java app so we sort of use [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for table name and column name.  This works pretty well with our DAO layer.  That means :

  1. no underscore;
  2. upper case for the first letter of each word of a table name (`PurchasedPoint`);
  3. lower case for the first letter of the first word of a column name and upper case letter for the first letter of all the other words (`userID`);
- For me, the word order inside a table name gives a hint on the relationship between tables.  For instance, if there is a table `Purchase` and a table `PurchasePoint` I can guess easily than there is some kind relationship between them.
- For intermediate table we would use something like `UserSite`.

Hope it can helps.